# Display addition of two value from Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I want two display addition of 2 values based on the values from Tkinter scale and it should be shown real-time when changing the value of each slider.

```
from Tkinter import *
def sel():
   selection = "Value = " + str(var2.get())
   label.config(text = selection)
root = Tk()
var1 = DoubleVar()
var2 = DoubleVar()
scale1 = Scale( root, variable = var1)
scale1.pack(anchor=CENTER)

scale2 = Scale( root, variable = var2,command=sel )
scale2.pack(anchor=CENTER)
label = Label(root)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is the error that I'm getting :

> return self.func(*args) TypeError: sel() takes no arguments (1
>   given)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The command option automatically pass one argument (the new scale value) to the procedure that is called. To make it work, change your `sel` function to:

```
def sel(*args):
   selection = "Value = " + str(var2.get())
   label.config(text = selection)
```